# How to model a specific counting process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

There are two types of events labelled $A$ and $B$. When an event of type $A$ happens there is a higher chance the next event will also be $A$ given by the transition matrix $p(A\to B)$ and $p(B \to A)$. Now, there are three counting processes $N_A$, $N_B$ and $N$, counting the number of events labeled $A$, $B$ and all events correspondingly. Events (irregardless of their label) come independently so that $N$ is a counting process of a homogenuous Poisson process.

How to describe the processes of $N_A$ and $N_B$? What are their intensities?

Comment: "irregardless" is a non-standard form mostly used humorously; the standard words are "regardless" and "irrespective".

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by "given by the transition matrix $p(A\to B)$ and $p(B\to A)$". Those are just two probabilities – but at least one of the other two entries of the transition matrix, $p(A\to A)$ and $p(B\to B)$, must also be non-zero for there to be a higher chance of $A$ after $A$?

Comment: How do you define the intensity of such a process?

Comment: Thanks, noted :) re 'irregardless'. The probability that a next event after $A$ is $A$ is $p(A \to A) \ne 0.5$ and the probability of $B$ after $A$ is $p(A \to B) = 1 - p(A \to A)$. Intensity as a limit of observing an event in an interval $[t, t+dt)$ divided by $dt$ and passing to the limit $dt \to 0$.

Comment: But are you interested in the marginal intensity? That seems very easy to calculate – find the equilibrium distribution of the transition matrix and multiply the total intensity of $N$ with the equilibrium occupations of the two states. So I assume you must be interested in something more interesting like a conditional intensity after an event of one of the types or the like?

Comment: I think conditional intensity will be even more interesting as I was planning to use the intensity to calculate an expected number of events marked $A$ or $B$ in a time interval. However, I would be even more interested in the expected number of events marked $A$ after the last event observed was $A$ (I guess I do not need the whole past history as everything is memoryless here).

Comment: Why is the intensity of the process after the last event observed was $A$ not simply $p(A\to A)$ times the intensity of $N$? It seems to me that the problem only becomes interesting if we condition on an event of type $A$ at some time but allow intervening events – then we have to account for the decay in the occupancy of state $A$ due to the intervening events. If there can't be intervening events, the problem seems trivial.

Comment: The kind of problem I'd like to understand is let's say the expectation of the number of $A$ events in a ten seconds interval unconditional on the last event or after the $A$ event is observed. I accept it might be trivial as stochastic analysis is not my strongest side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I still don’t fully understand what you want to calculate after our exchange in the comments, I’ll just calculate what I can and you can tell me whether it includes what you wanted :-)

The marginal (i.e. unconditional) intensity of the $A$ process is $p_A N$, where $p_A$ is the equilibrium distribution of the Markov process with the given transition matrix between states $A$ and $B$.

The intensity of the $A$ process conditional on the last event having been an $A$ event is $p(A\to A)N$.

The interesting bit is the intensity of the $A$ process conditional on there having been an $A$ event at time $\tau$. (The difference from the previous case is that this wasn’t necessarily the last event; there might have been intervening events of either type.)

Define the state of the process to be the last type of event that occurred. (Here I’m introducing an asymmetry in time by looking at the last instead of the next event, but that’s just because I find it easier to think about these things that way – the conditional probabilities are symmetric in the time difference, i.e. the conditional probability of an $A$ event at $\tau+\delta t$ is the same as at $\tau-\delta t$.)

This state is subject to a continuous-time Markov process with transition rate $\alpha=Np(A\to B)$ from state $A$ to state $B$ and $\beta=NP(B\to A)$ from state $B$ to state $A$. As explained in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain#Transient_behaviour), the resulting occupancy in state $A$ is

$$\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}e^{-(\alpha+\beta)(t-\tau)}\;,$$

an exponential decay from occupancy $1$ immediately after the event being conditioned on to the equilibrium occupancy of the discrete Markov process. The intensity of the $A$ process conditional on an $A$ event at time $\tau$ is $N$ times this occupancy.